# Something strange with this question

Tags: support, questions, login

I was checking on the [Cosmic Rays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580933/cosmic-rays-what-is-the-probability-they-will-affect-a-program) question and noticed that my vote wouldn't take.  I then closed the browser, cleaned out all the caches and came back.  Now I'm in SO just fine, but when I click on that particular question, it shows me in an unloggedin state.

Any ideas what's going on?

**Edit:** OK, it has now fixed itself.  I'm still interested in what was going on though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computer was affected by cosmic rays....

Or possibly the question asker was a secret member of the SO Dev team. In which case this was the rare thing that the person was describing.